# How to localize a custom type created in trainingcore-items.xml in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a custom type in items.xml.
How can I localize the item type? Where should I use the localized keyword for the item type to be localized?

```
    <itemtype code="Service" autocreate="true" generate="true">
           <deployment typecode="23456" table="Service"/>
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String" autocreate="true" generate="true">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                    <description>Service Code</description>
                    <modifiers unique="true" read="true" write="true"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="serviceType" type="ServiceType" autocreate="true" generate="true">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                    <description>Service Type</description>
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="years" type="java.lang.Integer" autocreate="true" generate="true">
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                    <description>Service Years</description>
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true"/>
                </attribute>
    </itemtype>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that you accepted is wrong.

You shouldn't do `type="localized:Service"`. What this does is let you set a different Service value for each language.

If what you wanted to do was add different labels/localization for the Service type, then [what you did in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948484/how-to-resolve-java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-im-localizing-an-enumtype-i) is correct.

For English localization/translation, define the localization in `trainingcore_locales_en.properties`:

```
type.Service.name=Service
type.Service.code.name=code
type.Service.serviceType.name=serviceType
type.Service.years.name=years

type.ServiceType.name=ServiceType
type.ServiceType.Basic.name=Basic
type.ServiceType.BasicOnsite.name=BasicOnsite
type.ServiceType.Advanced.name=Advanced
```

For German translation, set the translation in `trainingcore_locales_de.properties`.

Reference:

- Localization: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2011/en-US/8c05dbbc86691014a3fb88b6238b64b6.html

Answer (score 0):

[@geffchang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67949205) is correct. @Parvesh is wrong. It is not possible to have automagically localized Service just by adding `localized:`.

To do that you need to create new map-type:

```xml
<maptype code="localized:Service"
     argumenttype="Language"
     returntype="Service"
     autocreate="true"
     generate="false"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean you want to add this service as a localized attribute in another item type?

that can be done with something like this.

```
`   <attribute qualifier="service" type="localized:Service">
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>`
```

Comment: is it possible?